# How to monitor internet traffic on a Linksys E3000 router

Tags: networking, router, monitoring, traffic

I just got optical fiber installed in my place which gives me great download speeds. Now my ISP has a monthly download limit of 120GB, after that I gotta pay overages.

Now my setup is like this:

```
Fiber modem (1 port) -> Linksys E3000 router (4 ports + wifi).
```

All my gear is hooked up to the Linksys router (xbox, ps3, media center, office pc & 2 laptops).

I would like to keep track of the total ***"internet"*** bandwidth use of all devices, but exclude the normal network traffic, as that of course I don't pay for.

Is there something that I can install on the Linksys router that can keep track of that kinda of information?

Comment: In general, if your question asks "Is there something that I can install" then it's OT for Stack Overflow.  If you wanted to write some code that would do this task, then you'd be in the right place, but that sentence makes it sound like you don't want that.  I've flagged this for migration to Super User, where questions like this are on-topic.

Comment: There are third-party firmware images for your router which will give you that functionality (if it isn't already built in). I'm sure the folks on SuperUser will know more. You can "flag" your own question for migration if you'd like.

Comment: Ideally one could get that information using SNMP, but I don't know if the E3000 has it.  There is also sometimes part of universal plug-and-play, the Internet Gate Device, which can give some statistics.  Yet uPnP can be a bog security hole, so many people recommend it not be enabled.  Much will probably depend on what OS you want to get the data with.  For instance if it was some sort of Linux, and you had `miniupnpc` installed, you could look at the statistics with the command `upnpc -s`